# Node JS How to transform Json response to HTML page in Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, express

I'm wrote a nodejs method which make a http.get request which have a posts as response. The problem is that I want to transform this JSon response to a html customised page.

Following is the code I wrote:

```
router.get('/gettdatadate/', (req, res, next) => {

    let aa=req.query.imei;
    console.log(aa);
    Post.find({'imei.name': req.query.imei, test: { $exists: true } })

      .then((posts) => {
       const json= res.json(posts);
   })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

  });
```

Example of the response which I get from the server:

```
[
  {
    imei: { name: '865566048694354' },
    test: {
      tactileState: 'ignore',
      pixelState: 'ignore',
      greyState: 'ignore',
      date: '31 mai  a 12:23'
    },
    _id: '5ed393b85e785113d09d1f81',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    imei: { name: '865566048694354' },
    test: {
      date: '31 mai  a 12:23',
      bafleState: 'ignore',
      microState: 'ignore',
      vibreurState: 'ignore'
    },
    _id: '5ed393bf5e785113d09d1f82',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    imei: { name: '865566048694354' },
    test: {
      date: '31 mai  a 12:23',
      boutonState: 'ignore',
      kitState: 'ignore',
      usbState: 'ignore',
      batterieState: 'ignore'
    },
    _id: '5ed393c75e785113d09d1f83',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    imei: { name: '865566048694354' },
    test: {
      date: '31 mai  a 12:24',
      proximiteState: 'ignore',
      lumiereState: 'ignore'
    },
    _id: '5ed393da5e785113d09d1f84',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

that's the general format of my response I don't know what i should do with it to transform it to a Html customized page i neeed some helps and thank you

Comment: Will you reply to my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution it's to use ejs embedded java script templates [click here](https://ejs.co/)

Answer (score 0):

Search for documentation about template engines like PugJS: https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html